# "Konversation" Dictionary

Tags: 20.04, dictionary, irc

Where is the IRC program 'Konversation' dictionary?  I've had a few slip of the mouse when clicking to correct a misspelled word and instead added it to the dictionary.  I am using version 1.7.5